# How to get open cv to find all the circles of the plastic rings using HOUGH_GRADIENT?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to write a program to obtain the middle points between the plastic rings on this part. These x, y values will be later used to move a tool head to hit these middle points. Right now its hit or miss if it grabs all the the circles I want to grab and it almost never grabs that outside circle of the part, which I need.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
setItem=set()


image = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\jeffreyh\Documents\Pictures\Flash_Barrier_2.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(image, (800, 800))
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#blurred = cv2.blur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
#cv2.imshow("blurred", blurred)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

previous=0;
minR=3

for maxR in range(30,1500,23):
    # Finds circles in a grayscale image using the Hough transform
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.9, 10000, param1=200 ,param2=0.1 ,minRadius=minR ,maxRadius=maxR)
    
    minR+=23

    # Check to see if there is any detection
    if circles is not None:
        # If there are some detections, convert radius and x,y(center) coordinates to integer
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
        
        
        for (x, y, r) in circles:
            
            #Print X and Y coordinates of results
            #print(f"Circle Center - x: {x}, y: {y}")
             
            #Filter results for circles with center points at center of part
            if x < 417 and x > 403 and y < 406 and y > 393:
                # Draw the circle in the output image
                cv2.circle(img, (x, y), r, (0,255,0), 2)
                # Draw a rectangle(center) in the output image
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x - 1, y - 1), (x + 1, y + 1), (0,255,0), -1)
                setItem.add(r)

        #Find Middle Point Between Circles
        #if len(circles[0]) >= 2:
            #circle1 = circles[0][0]
            #circle2 = circles[0][1]
            #middle_point = ((circle1[0] + circle2[0]) // 2, (circle1[1] + circle2[1]) // 2)
            #Draw a point at the middle point
            #cv2.circle(img, middle_point, 2, (255, 0, 0), 3)
 
lst=sorted(setItem)
print("Length of List =", len(lst))
for item in lst:
    print(item)   

        
cv2.imshow("output", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)  

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

I have tried adjusting the values in which the max and min radius index at and have also tried playing around with the parameters of HOUGH_GRADIENT.

Comment: I have been working at it slowly and i feel like i am getting closer. I limit the amount of loops and set the minR and maxR to closer to where the circles should be to avoid getting doubles for each one.  [LATEST OUTPUT](https://imgur.com/a/nhn6F3Z)